# Why URLs from 'static' does not working for preview in flask?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to show some preview in Flask from user-uploaded images `static/uploads` and found that URLs generated by `url_for('static', filename=image_file_path)` do not work as I'd like.
I am getting out a path like: `/static/uploads/0321.jpg`
and after putting it in HTML `img src={{ image_url_list[0] }}` I see no preview (with URL: `http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/uploads/0321.jpg` if I copy the empty image address)
It is 404 error:`GET /static/uploads/03020011.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 -`
The file is in its place and I can access it inside the App if remove the first slash `static/uploads/0321.jpg`

Actually, I'd like to get the working URLs not only for preview but have them externally visible for other sites (but not freely explorable by other users just typing `static/uploads` in browser).
So, please, advise me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: pls put the code snippet and structure of the app folder. somehow, app could not your image path.

Comment: @simpleApp I am following Miguel Grinberg app structure from there [link](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) 

```microblog/
  venv/
  app/
    __init__.py
    routes.py
  microblog.py```

Comment: sorry, this does not help. Thanks

Comment: @simpleApp
Thank you, You were right and pointed me in the very right direction. There were two folders 'static/uploads' in different places. Thank you again!

Comment: @ DI S glad that you were able to resolve it! you are welcome!